# vue uses the fullcalendar resourceTimeGridDay view and cannot trigger select

Tags: vue.js

I use the fullcalendar resourceTimeGridDay view in vue2 version and can't trigger select, below is my code
It's not clear to me why handleDateSelect's console .log didn't print

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried setting select to true, and then changing the value of select to the handleDateSelect function in mounted, but it didn't work[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm78M.png)
I've tried setting select to true, and then changing the value of select to the handleDateSelect function in mounted, but it still doesn't work, and I want me to trigger select and add an event when I click somewhere in the calendar